# Fill an HTML page with data

Tags: android, html

I've got a ListView, each item return the same WebView class after a click. I would like to fill some fields inside the HTML page with code passed as argument to create different content with the same structure.

My webpage has code like this :

```
h2 {color: %@;}
section#title {background-color: %@;}
section#video a { color: %@; }
section#formation a { color: %@; }

<h1>%@</h1>
<p class="type-metiers">%@</p>
```

so I need to replace every `%@` of the HTML file. How can I do a loop that modify the content of an external file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the text from the HTML in a string, apply a regular expression to the string.

```
String s = html.toString();
String replaceWith = "Put something in this string";

source.replaceAll("%@", replaceWith);
```

If you want to replace with different values, you can use Pattern/Matcher

```
String s = html.toString();

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("%@");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) { 
    // Find each match in turn; 
    // Process your findings here;
}
```

Comment: It sounds good, thanks ! But I have to replace the %@ with different values inside the same page.

Comment: Added a solution so you can put in different values